# Disabling iOS multitask gesture recognizer during game play

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing a game where the user could draw using up to 5 fingers, 1 finger for each line.

When multitask gesture is enabled and the user try to draw using more than 4 fingers from right to left, the gesture recognizer from iOS on iPad switch to another application.

How can I programmatically disable this recognizer when the user enters on my application?

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for that.
There might be a way to consume the gesture, so it is not forwarded to the system, but I think the order of the messaging chain is in the other way.

You can only ask your users to disable the *Multitasking Gestures* in the System Preferences, under the *General* section. Not really great, I know.